# Doctest keeps putting in odd amount of whitespace?

Tags: python-3.x, python-module, doctest

I'm trying to put in doctests in the functions i'm defining like my professor wanted the class to, but it keeps failing on correct outputs on account of whitespace sort of being materialized out of nowhere, how would I combat this?

here's my code:

```
import math
def circle_area(radius):
    ''' >>> circle_area(5)
    78.54
    '''
    area = round(math.pi*(radius**2),2)
    if radius < 1 or radius > 1000:
        print('ERROR')
        return 0
    else:
        return area
```

output:

```
**********************************************************************
File "math_funcs.py", line 46, in __main__.circle_area
Failed example:
    circle_area(5)
Expected:
       78.54
Got:
    78.54
**********************************************************************
1 items had failures:
   1 of   1 in __main__.circle_area
***Test Failed*** 1 failures
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`>>> circle_area(5)` needs to be put on its own line, with the same indentation as the first line of the doctring. That is, instead of this:

```py
    ''' >>> circle_area(5)
    78.54
    '''
```

do this:

```py
    '''
    >>> circle_area(5)
    78.54
    '''
```

ETA: Here is the exact working test file that I used:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import math
def circle_area(radius):
    '''
    >>> circle_area(5)
    78.54
    '''
    area = round(math.pi*(radius**2),2)
    if radius < 1 or radius > 1000:
        print('ERROR')
        return 0
    else:
        return area

import doctest
doctest.testmod()
```

Comment: I am in awe at how bad this module is for actual testing, how is this still failing?:

`
*********************************************************************
File "math_funcs.py", line 47, in __main__.circle_area
Failed example:
    circle_area(5)
Expected:
    78.54 
Got:
    78.54
**********************************************************************
1 items had failures:
   1 of   1 in __main__.circle_area
***Test Failed*** 1 failures.
`

Comment: @LorinFordyce I did test it to make sure that it worked at my end. Try having the whitespace *exactly* how I have it. (Note that I used spaces not tabs. Not sure if you used tabs or not.)